# How do I extract a return value from a function and use the updated value?

Tags: python, function, variables

I would like to get the return value from this function and assign it a variable
if I put in "5" then we get 15 out but I want to keep using the updated variable afterwards in the next function. I would like to avoid joining the functions too.

To clarify, if you input this function then the result is 5+10 and 5+47. What I want as an answer is 5+10 and then 15+47.

```
y = input("here you input your number: ") 

def this_is_function(x):
    return int(x) + 10

def this_is_function2(x):
    return int(x) + 47

this_is_function(y)
this_is_function2(y)
```

Comment: You are simply *calling* the function. You need to *assign* the value to something. Like `y = this_is_function(y)`

Answer (score 2):

Currently you are ignoring the result of `this_is_function` (which is 15) and are just passing the same value `y` (which is 5) again to `this_is_function2`.

Save the result of `this_is_function` in a variable instead, and pass it to `this_is_function2`:

```
z = this_is_function(y)        # z is 5 + 10 = 15 (y is still 5)
result = this_is_function2(z)  # result is 15 + 47
```

If you don't need the original `y` anymore, you can also reuse the `y` variable name instead of using a new name, `z`, for the intermediate result.

```
y = this_is_function(y)        # y is now 5 + 10 = 15 (no longer 5)
result = this_is_function2(y)  # result is 15 + 47
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting the input to the second function (equation) to be the output of the first, then you can do just that:

```
y = input("here you input your number: ") 

def this_is_function(x):
    return int(x) + 10

def this_is_function2(x):
    return int(x) + 47
```

^leaving all this the same

Then using this:

```
this_is_function2(this_is_function(y))
```

You can now see that the input to `this_is_function2` is `this_is_function(y)` and the input to `this_is_function` is `y`

So writing it as I would solve a math problem - and as python performs this when debugging:

```
this_is_funtion2(this_is_function(y))    # Original line
```

```
this_is_funtion2(this_is_function(5))    # y = 5
```

```
this_is_funtion2(15)                     # this_is_function(5) = 15
```

```
62                                       # this_is_function2(15) = 62
```